# can css files be created from jade templates

Tags: css, pug

I see a .styl file in a jade project with the following content. The file extension seems to suggest there is some jade rendering involved, but there is no code to do it. Is it possible to render css templates. Is this a template ?

input[type="text"]
  margin 0 1em .5em 0

input[type="checkbox"]
  margin 0 .5em 0 2em